# Unresolved External Symbol Error w/ Classes

Tags: c++, class, unresolved-external

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Phone
{
public:
    int countryCode, areaCode, mainNum;
    string type;
    Phone::Phone();
    void Phone::setPhone();
    void getPhone();
};

Phone::Phone()
{
    countryCode = 0;
    areaCode = 0;
    mainNum = 0;
    type = "HOME";
}

void setphone()
{
    Phone phone;
    cout << "Enter a country code: ";
    cin >> phone.countryCode;
    cout << "Enter an area code: ";
    cin >> phone.areaCode;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> phone.mainNum;
    cout << "Enter a type (HOME, OFFICE, FAX, CELL, or PAGER): ";
    cin >> phone.type;
}

int main()
{
    Phone p;
    Phone();
    p.setPhone();
    cout << p.countryCode << "-" << p.areaCode << "-" << p.mainNum << " " << p.type << endl;
}
```

This code gives me this error

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Phone::setPhone(void)" (?setPhone@Phone@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\Adam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication22\ConsoleApplication22\Source.obj    ConsoleApplication22
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\adam\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication22\Debug\ConsoleApplication22.exe 1   1   ConsoleApplication22
```

From what I can tell there isn't anything outright wrong, just looking for some fresh eyes to look at it.

I've been searching and have found no answer, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

First change your class declaration to:

```
Phone(); // remove Phone::
void setPhone(); // Phone::
```

Then `setPhone` method:

```
void Phone::setPhone() // add Phone:: and correct name to setPhone, not setphone
{
    Phone phone;
    cout << "Enter a country code: ";
    ...
```